# How to use elasticsearch in python application?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch(v6.4.0) running on windows 10 machine and also a python(v3.6.0) application with angular 5 frontend and mongodb as backend.I want to use elasticsearch with python so that I can send data from UI to insert into mongodb as well as create index in elasticsearch with same data.How to achieve this?

I succeeded to connect to elasticsearch server from python.But stuck at creating index and querying indexed data.

Please help.

Regards,
Vidyashree

Comment: Use this(https://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to learn indexing and querying.

Comment: Thanks for your  response.I solved it using below code ,                     
                                                                                    
    es=ElasticSearch() 
    es.index(index=index_name,doc_type=doc_type_name,body=data)  where body is data to be stored on which search can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do indexing using

```
es = ElasticSearch()
es.index('indexName', 'type', 'indexQuery').
```

And searching from:

```
es.search(index=indexName',doc_type= type,body= searchQuery)
```